# What is the difference between last and publishLast operator in rxJS?

Tags: rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to pull the last emitted value from an observable. But rxJS have two operator [last()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/last)  and [publishLast()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/publishLast).

What is the difference between last and publishLast operator in rxJS?

Answer (score 2):

Two main differences:

1. [last()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/last.ts#L44) takes some parameters (*predictate* function to filter emitted value on some condition and a default value);
2. [publishLast()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/publishLast.ts#L65) returns a **ConnectableObservable** from `multicast()` with `AsyncSubject()` as its parameter, which subscribes to the source, while `last()` returns an Observable that emits only the last item or an NoSuchElementException if no such items are emitted (**by using** `takelast()` **operator**). And this is the cruitial difference, because `takeLast`:

> Remembers the latest count values, then emits those only when the
>   source completes.

So if  source haven't completed, `last()` will not emit, while `publishLast()` will emit.

Also in order for returned observable from `publishLast()` to start emitting, you must `connect()` it (because it is a ConnectableObservable).

```
const ob$ = source.pipe(publishLast())
ob$.connect()
```

And for Typescript compiler to be happy, cast it's type also:

```
const ob$ = source.pipe(publishLast()) as ConnectableObservable<an>;
```